# Accessing @keyframes through JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a html/css/js modal working on a fadeIn and slideIn premise but I can't seem to make it do the reverse on a close...it simply makes a hard jump to being "not there."

My close function in JS is simply taking the modal.style.display="none" but is there a way to access the @keyframes I've added in my css to make a smooth reverse?

HTML:

```
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<button id="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="modal">

<div id="modal-content">
    <div id="modal-header">
        <span id="close">&times</span>
        <h2>modal header</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal body</p>
        <p>Some other text in the modal body</p>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-footer">
        <h2>modal footer</h2>
    </div>

</div><!--modal-content-->
</div><!--modal div-->
```

CSS:

```
#modal
{
position: fixed;
z-index:1;
left:0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 0.4s;
display: none;
}

#modal-content
{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
backgroun-color: #fefefe;
width: 100%;
-webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: slideIn;
animation-duration: 0.4s;

}

#close
{
color: white;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#close:hover, #close:focus
{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

#modal-header
{
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

#modal-footer
{
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

#modal-body
{
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: white;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes slideIn
 {
 from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
 to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
 }

@keyframes slideIn
 {
 from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
 to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn
{
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn
{
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

var button = document.getElementById("button");

var close = document.getElementById("close");

button.onclick = function()
{
modal.style.display="block";
};

close.onclick = function()
{
modal.style.display="none";
};

window.onclick = function(event)
{
if(event.target == modal)
{
modal.style.display="none";
}
};
```

Comment: You cannot animate anything after setting `element.style.display='none'`.

Comment: I think you can easily achieve it with jQuery, if you don't mind using it. Besides all the animations are `Opacity: 0 to 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on posted question:

- one cannot access @keyframes rules - without **huge hacks** (getting css as a text and parsing rules with regular expression, and even that you can't do in 100% cases)
- accessing keyframe rules wouldn't help in what you are asking
- Any animation is impossible after setting `display:none`
- however, you can dynamically generate, activate, stop and play-again @keyframe animations via Javascript library like [jQuery.keyframes](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed comment!